# Munge Unorthodox Data in from Excel or PDF to Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pandas

I have PDFs listing donors to institutions; [here's](http://www.aboutlincolncenter.org/pdfs/Lincoln-Center-Annual-Report-12-13.pdf#page=19) an example. I can convert them to excel, where I'll get something that looks like this:

[image]

Needless to say, when I just do `pd.read_excel(filename)` the result is not fun.

Is there a good way, Pythonic way convert these to a format like this:

```
Name,Amount
The City of New York,2000000
The State of New York,2000000
United States Department of Transportation,2000000
Michael R. Bloomberg,2000000
...
Ronnie and Lawrence D. Ackman,1000000
American Express,1000000
```

Comment: Why not fixup the formatting in excel so it's table freindly? and then you can either analyse in excel or export to csv and analyse using pandas/R? It looks like it would be quicker to use the mouse to copy and past everything around

Comment: yup that's what I am currently doing, but there are 100+ PDFs that are very similar and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of an approach to scripting

Comment: You might try one of the pdf 2 text converters (e.g. http://www.colorpilot.com/pdf2text.html).  Then in python you could read the text line by line and try to munge into something of a regular format.  If the PDFs don't follow the same format, this won't be much help.